# webpack-dev-server nfs mount file watcher

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the watching plugin configured, and if I edit files on my VM, it works great. However, I have an NFS share, and I edit my files on the host. The filewatcher on the VM does not pick up changes on the NFS share.

For other reasons, I do need this to be an NFS share. Is there any way that I can make this work?

The [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_availability) state "You can still use fs.watchFile, which uses stat polling, but it is slower and less reliable."

Comment: I've had this same issue, I was using vagrant though so I ended up using two plugins vagrant gatling-rsync-auto for synching from host to guest machine and vagrant rsync-back to sync from guest to host. Don't know if this helps you in any way, maybe there is an rsync implementation available for node.js you can use

Comment: Is there a way to have vagrant-rsync-back work automatically like gatling?

Comment: unfortunately not out of the box, I just run it manually when I've done something like npm install, it's a bit clunky but hasn't slowed me down too much and is the most reliable way I've found so far - that being said I would love to know if there is a more 'automatic' way of doing it....

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 running on Oracle VM VirtualBox on Windows 8.1 using:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
```

I think there's a decent chance this will also fix the issue with other configurations.

Comment: Why do you think this fixes your issue can you add more information based on your theory? thanks

Comment: I read "somewhere" that the Linux file watcher API, when in the VM, cannot detect file changes from outside the VM. The plugin does not use this API. Perhaps it keeps checking file timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this options into your webpack config.

```
 watchOptions: {
        poll: true
 }
```

You have do this because of Vagrant/Virtual box filesystem mounting specifics.