# Webpack doesn't pass watchOptions to watcher

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've got a webpack problem, and I want to confirm that the fix will require me to fork the repo (and if so, how I might go about getting that merged back in :D)

Problem: We're using the webpack npm module environment in a development vm we're building where the code itself is edited on the host machine, and synced to the dev vm to be run using a mounted share file. This seems to be working fine, except that code change events don't seem to be being detected on the vm unless the edit it coming from the vm itself, rather than the host.

It seems we are experiencing this issue: [webpack-dev-server nfs mount file watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954774/webpack-dev-server-nfs-mount-file-watcher), which can be fixed by setting watchOptions.poll to true.

However setting that in our webpack config doesn't seem to do anything, so I went hunting through the code, and found this in webpack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js:

```
function NodeWatchFileSystem(inputFileSystem) {
    this.inputFileSystem = inputFileSystem;
    this.watcherOptions = {
        aggregateTimeout: 0
    };
    this.watcher = new Watchpack(this.watcherOptions);
}
```

So it seems the watcherOptions aren't being passed into the watchpack instance? And indeed, when I added poll: true to the options, it worked wonderfully. So I'm wondering if there's a reason for the watchOptions not being respected in the node plugin environment, and if not, what the proceedures are for me rectifying the situation, and how long it would take a fork to be merged into master. The contributors section didn't seem to mention anything about community forks?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

So turns out rather than being passed through webpack options, the webpackDevMiddleware only takes options through the options it gets passed after the compiler, like so

```
const middleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    silent: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
      <------------ watchOptions go here
  });
```

in the boilerplate we were using it was in middlewares/frontendMiddleware.js